# Applying a sap.ui.model.Filter on two sap.m.Table columns combined

Tags: sapui5

Two columns `firstName` and `lastName`.
How can the `filter` method of a binding be used so that a query from a search field where a person enters `John Doe` keep records where the concatenation of `firstName` + `" "` + `lastName` matches?

Note: I'm doing this on a client side operation mode so no backend filtering solutions please.

Comment: you need a third invisible column where you simply bind those two fields into one column. then apply filter on this field.

Comment: What about 2 Filter objects with AND operation? (of course you need to split the search value before applying)

Comment: @zyrex Wouldn't work, AFAIK filtering is done on the binding and not on the value in a column. But I'll add a property with the full name and bind this to a hidden column. Thanks

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych Wouldn't work for names composed of multiple parts as you cannot now where to split.

Comment: What about using a custom filter function? https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html "test"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution is using Custom Filter as pointed out by: @Andrii.

So, we can create a custom filter which will run for every row in the table and based on the returned boolean value from
the custom filter a row is rendererd on screen. Filter API: [Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.9/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html)

So, below is the running code:

```
handleSearch: function(e) {
    var sQuery = e.getParameter('query'); // Fecth search term
    var oCustomFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
        path:"", // this refers to binding path of each row.
        test: function(oNode) {
            var oValue = oNode.fname + " " +oNode.lname;
            if (oValue.indexOf(sQuery) !== -1) {
                return true; // row will be rendererd
            } else {
                return false; // row will not be rendererd
            }

        }
    });
    var oBinding = this._table.getBinding('items');
    oBinding.filter(oCustomFilter);
}
```

TABLE:

```
            <Table
                id='idTable'
                items= "{/}"
            >
                <columns>
                    <Column
                        headerText='FName'
                    />
                    <Column
                        headerText='LName'
                    />  
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem>
                        <cells>
                            <Text
                                text='{fname}'
                            />
                            <Text
                                text='{lname}'
                            />
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
```

Let me know if you need any additional infomation. :)